# Fortify cross site scriting on response.binarywrite

Tags: c#, xss

When I scanned code with fortify it is showing cross site scripting vulnerability on following code

```
Response.ContentType = "Image/PNG";
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Logo");
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "reflected-xss");
Response.BinaryWrite(data.LogoFileData);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
```